# Does GraphQL-go support upload file?

Tags: go, graphql-go

As the title, does `GraphQL-go` support upload files?

Or I must create an endpoint besides my `GraphQL-endpoint` to POST files?

Comment: hello, did you finally create endpoint or combine it to graphql mutation?

Comment: I created an endpoint.

Comment: ok, thanks @khue bui

Comment: I believe there is a link in the graphq-go readme